# Modify android:exported programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

To provide an API for other apps, we can export our own content providers, services and broadcast receivers by using `android:exported="true"` in our apps' `AndroidManifest.xml`.

However, I want that the user is able to deactivate the API features in the app, meaning that I want to set the `exported="false"` flag dynamically in the code. Is that possible?

Or is the only way to achieve this by checking inside my content providers/services whether the API is enabled or not and do nothing/provide nothing if the API was disabled?

---

To understand why I want to disable the API programmatically, here is an example:

User A wants to use the API, thus it must be enabled.
However, user B secured the app, for example by setting a password that is required to access the app and its content. But if someone got access to the device he could access the API to bypass the password protection. Thus, user B should be able to deactivate the API from the Apps' settings.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @Biggie, any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can implement modification of `android:exported` setting, but you could try to achieve what you want by disabling/enabling your components.

For instance, to disable a component you can do something like below:

```
packageManager
  .setComponentEnabledSetting(
       new ComponentName(
           context,
           /*Your Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, or ContentProvider*/.class),
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**WARNING:** think twice about using just component enabling/disabling (or altering `android:export` if it's possible) to secure your API as it may be that components can be reenabled by other apps or someone (rooted device? adb?)